# Microsoft Teams invites sent from Outlook Calendar don't have a link to the meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-outlook-365

Two of my colleagues have the same problem in that Microsoft Teams invites sent from Outlook Calendar don't have a link to the meeting.  The actual text is there saying "Join Microsoft Teams Meeting" but the text isn't linked to anything.

It works fine for me but not for them. We're all using the Office 365 version of Outlook and the Teams plugin appears to be installed and working.  Why would the link not be appearing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the Format Text format is set to HTML, rather than plain text. Plain/Rich text don't support HTML links. Format Text is on the ribbon bar.

[image]

Comment: This solves it for that particular meeting, but it reverts to "plain text" every time a new meeting is generated. It's infuriating that you have to keep changing it each time - and if you forget, it goes out in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Agree, email format may cause issues like this, please ensure that you are sending meeting invites with HTML format. Or you could try sending teams meeting invites on your web mail and see if the issue has any difference.

Similar issues:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/calendar-invite-doesnt-show-the-join-teams-meeting/8cf5ae6b-71b8-4573-8b85-248df31a2e88?page=3

Answer (score 0):

This helped us after our client was updated to Outlook 365.

https://andys-tech.blog/2021/02/microsoft-teams-invitations-show-as-plain-text/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).